# Getting json data and saving session?

Tags: php, html

In my application, I am trying to do the login part where the user submits a form using POST to my own REST API which accepts the POST request.

In my API I have set it to return a JSON object after extracting data from the database. I want this API to be used in an android application also to fetch JSON data so I can't redirect in the API code back to the home page.

How can I redirect back to the home page with the JSON object and save the session data before loading the home page?

The home page should show in a corner that the user has logged in.

```html
<form class = "form" action =<?php $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ?> "/shades-api/get/login.php" method = "POST">
...
<button type="submit" name ="usignin" class="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

API code

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
  session_start();
}
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/shades-api/services/userservice.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  if(isset($_POST['email']) && !is_null($_POST['email']) && trim($_POST['email']) != ""){
    if(isset($_POST['password']) && !is_null($_POST['password']) && trim($_POST['password']) != ""){

        $UserService = new Services\UserService();
        $json_obj = $UserService->login($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
      echo json_encode($json_obj);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ajax if you are using REST API
write below jquery this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var _form = $(this);
        var data = _form.serialize();
        var url = _form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                        alert("Login successfully");
                       // write your redirect page
                        $('<a href="index.php" id="aa"></a>').appendTo("body");
                        document.getElementById("aa").click();                  


            },
            error: function() {}
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried ajax jquery to send data and retrieve from my API. however it did not work, the response im getting is 0.

I sent data to an another online api and it worked perfectly fine but the problem is with my api. I even tried sending data without a form and only just hardcoded inputs but none of that worked

Comment: do you have postman application from there you can debug your api.

Comment: yes it finally worked after two days of working. the problem was a dumb mistake i used. instead of putting the relative path i typed the absolute path and for some reason it did not work with ajax.